# SQL Server Launchpad Service keeps shutting down

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2019, windows-server, windows-server-2019

We have a problem with the Launchpad Service shutting down and doesn't come back up. The service is has startup type "automatic", but when the server is restarted, or the sevice is stopped for some other reason, it's unable to start Launchpad Service back up. The service is ran by our own service account to get the proper rights (and not by Local Service/System). Every time this happens (which is about once a week) we have to go through the following procedure:

1. Enter the SQL Server Configuration Manager
2. Try to start Launchpad Service - which fails
3. Change the account to Local Service
4. Try again to start Launchpad Service - now it starts
5. Change the account back to our own account
6. The service is restarted and now it's working

This is the system we are running:

- Windows Server 2019 Standard 10.0, Version 1809 (OS Build 17763.2458)
- SQL Server 2019 15.0.4178.1

This did not occur before when running on Windows Server 2016 and SQL Server 2016. So it seems to be some bug in the later Windows Server/SQL Server versions.

Has anyone else experienced this? Any ideas of how to solve this?

**Additional information:**

When trying to start the service again this popup appears:

"The request failed or the service did not respond in a timely fashion.
Consult the event log or other applicable error logs for details."

In the event log there's one System log containing:

"The SQL Server Launchpad (MSSQLSERVER) service terminated unexpectedly.  It has done this 2 time(s)."

And a bunch of audit failure secutiry logs:

[image: event logs]

We have tried to give the service account all the required priveliges. When the service is restarted in step 6 we also get the same Security event logs but no error popup and the service is starting and running as it should.

Comment: can you please share the error in the event viewer?

Comment: I added some info with event logs

Comment: That's the Windows Event Log, but SQL Server has it's own [Error Log](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/configuration-manager/viewing-the-sql-server-error-log?view=sql-server-ver15) as well, which may contain additional information at the time of the Launchpad Service shutting down. Please try to analyze the SQL Server Error Log and post any relevant details from it as well.

Comment: mmm, it sounds like this one:

https://support.microsoft.com/it-it/topic/kb4014734-fix-sql-server-launchpad-service-fails-to-start-if-the-installed-version-of-r-services-in-database-is-different-from-the-database-engine-in-sql-server-2016-7ee260b5-1ec3-3e57-4ac4-0c81a4b39695

but with sql server 2019


please make sure you have TCP enabled on the server.

Comment: please look at this:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/machine-learning/troubleshooting/known-issues-for-sql-server-machine-learning-services?view=sql-server-2017#8-launchpad-services-fails-to-start-if-the-version-is-different-from-the-r-version

Comment: @J.D. It's a bit hard to search since I don't know exactly when it's stopped. The only thing I could find regarding launchpad was this entry: "Resource governor reconfiguration encountered an issue (HRESULT code : 0x80040002, reason: Construction of Launchpad Connection failed), while sending active external resource pool ids to launchpad. This will not fail reconfigure."

Comment: @MBuschi I checked your links, they both refer to a conflict in versions. I checked both launchpad.exe and sqldk.dll and the file versions matched (2019.150.4178.1). As for TCP I'll have to look into that